# read RFID data through serial with bash

Tags: bash, serial-port, rfid, gnu-screen

I am attempting to read the contents of an RFID card with a bash script using a RFID reader I got from sparkfun, however the most promising piece of code I have found for it is:

```
#!/bin/sh
while :
do
  rfid=`screen /dev/cu.usbserial-A600JNHR 9600`  
  echo "RFID #: $rfid"  
  sleep 1  
done
```

which does what it is supposed to, only it never exits `screen`, so the variable cannot be checked against a known tag to perform an action.

My question: what do I need to do to get the tag in a variable so that I can use it to check and perform an action? Is this piece of code going about it all wrong, or do I just need to add an extra line or two to process the data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may work for you

```
#!/bin/bash
while read -r rfid; do
  echo "RFID #: $rfid"  
  sleep 1  
done < /dev/cu.usbserial-A600JNHR
```

Comment: thanks but I get a blinking cursor like its waiting for input but when I scan a tag I get nothing showing up

Comment: run `cat /dev/cu.usbserial-A600JNHR` then scan a tag and paste any output that you see in a [pastebin.com](http://www.pastebin.com) link

Answer (score 0):

I got it thank you SiegeX I double checked and had used tty instead of cu for the code, here I had given the default that I had found and when I changed it I grabbed the tty.